# Get all Folders and Images from Google Cloud Storage with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-storage

I am using [laravel-google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/Superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage) to store images and retrieve them one by one. Is it possible that I can get all the folders and images from the Google Cloud Storage? If possible, how do I get this done?

I was trying to use this [flysystem-google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/Superbalist/flysystem-google-cloud-storage) to retrieve it but they are similar to the first link I have provided.

What I want to achieve is I want to select an image using the Google Cloud Storage with all the folders and images in it and put it in my form instead of selecting an image from my local.

**UPDATE:**

This is what I have tried so far base from this [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.39.2/storage/storageclient).

```
    $storageClient = new StorageClient([
        'projectId' => 'project-id',
        'keyFilePath' => 'myKeyFile.json',
    ]);
    $bucket = $storageClient->bucket('my-bucket');
    $buckets = $storageClient->buckets();
```

Then tried adding `foreach` which returns empty and also I have 6 folders in my Bucket.

```
foreach ($buckets as $bucket) {
    dd($bucket->name());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a week since my post has not been answered. I'll just post and share to anyone of what I did since last week.

I am using Laravel 5.4 at the moment.

So I installed [laravel-google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/Superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage) and [flysystem-google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/Superbalist/flysystem-google-cloud-storage) in my application.

I created a Different controller since I am retrieving the images from Google Cloud Storage via Ajax.

All you need to do is to get your Google Cloud Storage credentials which can be located in your Google Cloud Storage Dashboard > Look for the **APIs** then click the link below that stated "Go to APIs overview > Credentials. Just download the credentials which is in JSON file format and put it in your root or anywhere you wanted to (I still don't know where should I properly put this file). Then the next is we get your Google Cloud Storage **Project ID** which can be located in the Dashboard.

Then this is my setup in my controller that connects from my Laravel application to Google Cloud Storage which I am able to Upload, Retrieve, Delete, Copy files.

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Plugin\GetWithMetadata;
use Superbalist\Flysystem\GoogleStorage\GoogleStorageAdapter;

class GoogleStorageController extends Controller
{

    // in my method
    $storageClient = new StorageClient([
        'projectId' => 'YOUR-PROJECT-ID',
        'keyFilePath' => '/path/of/your/keyfile.json',
    ]);

    // name of your bucket
    $bucket = $storageClient->bucket('your-bucket-name');
    $adapter = new GoogleStorageAdapter($storageClient, $bucket);
    $filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);

    // this line here will retrieve all your folders and images
    $contents = $filesystem->listContents();

    // you can get the specific directory and the images inside 
    // by adding a parameter
    $contents = $filesystem->listContents('directory-name');

    return response()->json([
        'contents' => $contents
    ]);
}
```